# Add coloring rules for specified language keywords in lstinputlisting

Tags: listings, color, sourcecode

I would like to add coloring definition for e.g. `@Override` in java files. How can I do that ?

So far I have the following coloring definitions :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{listings} % for code snippets

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=4pt,
  numberstyle=\scriptsize\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=2
}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[label={lst:sourcefile}]{codefile.java}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the form of the words you want to highlight? Do they all start by `@`? What kind of highlight (color, font shape, etc.) are you thinking about? Be more specific. And please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Jubobs Done :). I would like to add coloring rule for all annotations (starting with `@`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To highlight all words starting with `@` and followed by a space or newline, you can use the `moredelim` key like so:

```
moredelim=[s][⟨style⟩]{@}{\ },
```

where `⟨style⟩` can be any combination of macros for font family, size, shape, series, colour specification, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{listings} % for code snippets
\usepackage{filecontents}

% http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873633/should-i-comment-override-method-in-java
\begin{filecontents*}{codefile.java}
/** Interface */
public Interface IFoo {
      /** method */                 
      public String getFoo();
    }
/** Class implementing interface */        
public Class Foo implements IFoo {

  /** Should be here documentary comment for overrided method getFoo() ???*/      
  @Override    
  public String getFoo() {
      return "Foo";
  }
}
\end{filecontents*}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=4pt,
  numberstyle=\scriptsize\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  moredelim=[s][\color{red}]{@}{\ },
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=2
}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[label={lst:sourcefile}]{codefile.java}
\end{document}
```